# Can two elliptic curve point multiplications have a same resulted point?

Tags: elliptic-curves

Is it possible for $aG \equiv bG$, with $a, b$ are scalars and $G$ is a point on the curve?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, it is possible, but only if $a, b$ differ by a multiple of the order of the point $G$.

When we perform elliptic curve cryptography, we select a curve and a point $G$ where the order is a large prime (typically, circa the field size).  When we select a random multiplier, we most often select a random one uniformly between 1 and $\operatorname{order}(G)-1$; if both $a, b$ were selected that way, then the only way for $aG = bG$ would be if $a=b$